# How to identify the docker host ip to use when running a jenkins container

Tags: docker, networking, jenkins

I have docker machine installed on windows OS and have pulled in Jenkins image from docker hub. I then run the below commands:

```
docker volume created myjenkins-data
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v myjenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

I received the admin key for Jenkins in the logs. I've confirmed that my container is still running status:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
2854c7d83879        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr..."   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   quizzical_cray
```

Now, I need to log into 8080 port to view the Jenkins web app. But I do not know which host ip to use. I identified the docker host ip with the command "docker-machine ip" and got the ip address: 192.168.99.100. But using 192.168.99.100:8080 did not bring up Jenkins app. I also tried using docker inspect to get the container's ip, but port 8080 didn't work on those ips as well. Which ip address do i use to see the Jenkins app that is running in the container?

Answer (score 1):

First, double-check if http://localhost:8080 is not enough.

[Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) (through [vpnkit](https://github.com/moby/vpnkit), if you are using [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)) should have done the port-forwarding for you.

If you are using the legacy docker toolbox (VirtualBox), then you [need port-forwarding (issue 4115)](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4115).